# Is there anyway to implement Proof of stake (PoS) in Ethereum?

Tags: go-ethereum, smart-contract-wallets

I am looking for a mechanism that implements Proof of stake (PoS) in ethereum. I am working on a mechanism that closely related to PoS, however, I do not find any other platforms. I was hoping that Proof of Authority (PoA) somehow related to PoS but I get confused by the implementation available on the web.

If you have any knowledge  and tutorials that a complete private implements similar to PoS or PoA, please help to get those information. I also have a question that in PoA, regardless of the reputation, the nodes chances to become miner is random and equally weighted?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Lauri Peltonen , Here is the question that I asked.

Answer (score 0):

Binance Smart Chain is basically a PoS implementation of Ethereum. The [code](https://github.com/binance-chain/bsc) is public.

And here is a [link to the documentation](https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/guides/bsc-intro.html) where you will also find the whitepaper.

Comment: @ Undead8, Thank you very much. Lately, I was looking at the Substrate that says they support PoS too. Can I use Substrate for that implementation too? By the way, I have recently joined here and my reputation is 11 but I need 15 reputations in order to thumbs up and accept the answer. Could you please help me to reach that milestone?

Comment: I don't know what substrate is.

Comment: Here is the official documentation: https://substrate.dev/docs/en/knowledgebase/getting-started/